# Use of "contretemps"

Tags: articles, grammatical-number

According to Oxford Dictionaries, *contretemps* means ["an unexpected and unfortunate occurrence"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contretemps). What is the plural of it, if it exists, and how do I use it in a sentence? Do I say "contretemps startled me"? Can the word be used with an article?

Comment: Do you do research? I am starting to recognize your name.

Comment: Yeah, but only vocabulary and usage of words. It is my hobbie and passion. It my vocation and avocation. :-) I teach people, and for that I need to keep learning.

Comment: Well... okay then. Just wondering.

Comment: Is the question about how the plural is used or about two different things, what the plural is, and separately how to use the singular in a sentence? Your accepted answer doesn't address the plural situation.

Comment: The string "an unexpected and unfortunate occurrence" is obviously from a dictionary (I've added a link). That dictionary will also have the plural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contretemps is a French expression that has been adopted into English. Since it is a noun, you have to use 'a' or 'the' before it. It means 'against time' (contra + temps) and is usually used to describe embarrassing situations.

> He caused **a** minor contretemps by knocking over his drink.
>
> **The** contretemps of this is that you filled the form all wrong.

[Here are some more examples for your reference.](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/contretemps)

As for your example (contretemps started me), it is incorrect in its usage although it might be literally correct ("The minor embarrassing event startled me").

Comment: “Since it is a noun, you have to use ‘a’ or ‘the’ before it”—this is in no way true. There is no requirement that an article must always be used with nouns. The indefinite plural, for example, has no article, and there are many cases where singulars without articles are used, too.

Comment: Perhaps I phrased it wrong. The usage of contretemps has be preceded with an article otherwise you'll be unable to use it in English.

Comment: Again, that is not true. You can use _contretemps_, just like any other noun, without article in various different contexts. “Contretemps with your colleagues are par for the course for a chef”, for example, is perfectly good English.

Comment: As far as I know it needs an article to be used correctly and this is after confirming with a French/English logolepsic. I will add, that after grilling him he did admit that a participle can be used instead, but it can't be used standing alone as per your example.

Comment: [Some more examples of usage.](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/contretemps).

Comment: Well, he is wrong. It _can_ be used without an article if the context and syntax calls for a noun with no article. In your link, you’ll notice that _four_ of the examples have no article (two that have possessive determiners instead and two that have bare nouns).

Comment: You're right. Those examples do give bare noun examples. Thank you for pointing that out. I will have words with my friend.

Answer (score 0):

A French expression. You may find it occasionally in literature, but I don't think that it is used in everyday language. But there are people who want to show that they know French and they decorate their English with French expressions. If you can imagine a sentence where you need a plural, the plural has the same form.

French contre means against and French temps means time. In English contretemps is used in the sense of something/an event that occurs at a time when it is not convenient for you.